# Send a message when the score gets an update - Telegram Bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Hope you all are doing great! I developed a telegram bot that posts the score of the match in the telegram group. I already did most of the part but there is something I didn't able to figure out

How to post score in the group when the score is updated or when there is a change in over. I also tried to keep the API in while loop and set a time delay (sleep();) but that didn't work as I expected because, at one time, execution time would be timed out (endless loop). So what is the best way to achieve this?

Here is my code

```
<?php

$token = 'xyz';
$group_name = 'xyz';

$ipl = file_get_contents('https://cricket-api.vercel.app/cri.php?url=https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/37631/kkr-vs-srh-49th-match-indian-premier-league-2021');  // cricbuzz unofficial API

$ipl_data = json_decode($ipl, true);

$current_score = $ipl_data['livescore']['current'];


$bot = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$group_name}&text={$current_score}";
$hit = file_get_contents($bot);


?>
```

Comment: Thank you for referring to these useful links! But do you know any solution to the problem that I'm facing? @RiggsFolly

Comment: To make it  more simplify, I'm using telegram bot API to post score of cricket in group but I need to send message only when there is change in the score

Comment: Then you are going to have to remember the last score so you can tell its changed!#

Comment: I'm trying to make this process automated! Are you telling me that I have to manually rehit the API when scores get changed?

Comment: No when you hit the API to find the score, you need to know what it was last time you hit it, so you can tell if its changed. So possibly you need to store the last GOT score in the session, or a database, or even just a file

Comment: Understood! Will try it

Comment: I did little bit more research on it and I found there is one more method to achieve it! Long polling

Comment: I realized what I did was long polling but the same problem (max execution time) I posted one more question regarding this problem with more clarity