# Store API previous value and compare with new one

Tags: php, api

I developed a telegram bot whose job is to post the score of a cricket match in the telegram group. The score needs to be posted only when the new score is updated. I'm trying to store the old score in the session and then compare it with the new one.

If both values (old and new) didn't match, post the score in the group but for some unknown reason, it is not working

Here is my code

```
<?php

session_start();

set_time_limit(0);


$token = 'xyz';
$group_name = 'xyz';


while(true){

$ipl = file_get_contents('https://cricket-api.vercel.app/cri.php?url=https://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scores/37632/dc-vs-csk-50th-match-indian-premier-league-2021');  

$ipl_data = json_decode($ipl, true);

$current_score = $ipl_data['livescore']['current'];
        
if($current_score != $_SESSION['old_score']){
  $bot = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$group_name}&text={$current_score}";
  $hit = file_get_contents($bot);      
} 

$_SESSION['old_score'] = $current_score;
    


sleep(10);    

}
 

?>
```

Comment: You asked this already: [Send a message when the score gets an update - Telegram Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427205/send-a-message-when-the-score-gets-an-update-telegram-bot) Duplicate questions are explicitly prohibited in order to maintain content quality. Please don't re-post; edit your original question instead.

Comment: I didn't repost the same problem! Both questions are having different problems. It is basically continuation of previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at that

```
$_SESSION['old_score'] = $current_score;

if($current_score != $_SESSION['old_score'])
```

Your sessions `"old_score"` always equals `$current_score`
Try first your `if`, then change session field

```
if($current_score != $_SESSION['old_score']){
       
} 

$_SESSION['old_score'] = $current_score;
```

Comment: Sorry but the same problem still persists.

Comment: Didn't post any message in the group when the score updated

Comment: (if statement is still not executing despite score update)

Comment: It worked man! Don't know why it didn't work last time! but working perfectly fine now! Thank you so much